# Copy text from one text file to another

Tags: c#, .net

Could someone demonstrate how to copy all lines of a text file to another one (without overwriting the destination file, e.g.:

File A copies lines to File B (without overwriting the existing lines in FileB - adding them)

Answer (score 4):

This looks like homework, so I'll just give you some pointers.

Open the first file with the `FileMode.Open` and `FileAccess.Read` parameters. Open the second file with `FileMode.Append` and `FileAccess.Write` parameters.

Loop through the first file, writing to the second one what you're reading from the first.

Look at the [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) class for more information.

Comment: Why not use methods from the File class instead? Looping over a FileStream is a bit redundant if can just call ReadLines and such IMO.

Comment: @Neowizard: `File.ReadLines` may be more convenient for the programmer, but vastly less useful to the user if the file is bigger than your RAM or your virtual address space.

Comment: @Timwi I completely agree, it's just that after working with files over 300MB using File.ReadLines I don't see a problem with it unless someone tells me we're talking about very (very!) large text files. If you're working with text files larger then your virtual address space you're doing something very different then just "Copy text from one text file to another" IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Here is *my solution*. Hope it helps:

```
    Dim fileAContent As String = ""

    Using strR As New IO.StreamReader(fileAPath)
        fileAContent = strR.ReadToEnd
    End Using

    Using strW As New IO.StreamWriter(fileBPath, True)
        strW.Write(fileAContent)
        strW.Flush()
    End Using
```

Second parameter of **StreamWriter** is the key. It will **append** content to the end of file.

First read all lines from the first file and after that append all of them to second file.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answer helps you. I wrote it in a way that you can follow to give you a good understanding of the steps.
To start, replace the files with yours then run the code to see if it gives you the result that you want.

```
var file1 = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file1.txt";
var file2 = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\file2.txt";

var file1Lines = File.ReadAllLines(file1);
var file2Lines = File.ReadAllLines(file2).ToList();

// before the copy
Console.WriteLine("**Before the copy**");
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(file2));

foreach (var l in file1Lines)
{
    file2Lines.Add(l);
}
File.WriteAllLines(file2, file2Lines);

// after the copy
Console.WriteLine("**After the copy**");
Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(file2));
```

Comment: This should work, however since the goal is add the lines from `file1` to `file2` it shouldn't be necessary to read the existing contents of `file2`; just append the contents of `file1` to what's already there.  It's more efficient and less lines of code to remove all usages of `file2Lines` and instead just add `File.AppendAllLines(file2, file1Lines);`.

Comment: @BACON doing it the way you suggest does not append the lines from the list properly. The first line of file1Lines is appended to the last line of file2

Comment: I see what you mean.  That really depends on if the files end on a newline character or not and what the desired behavior is.  If the appended text should begin on a new line then `File.AppendAllText(file2, Environment.NewLine);` can be inserted before the call to `File.AppendAllLines`, or change the call to `File.AppendAllLines(file2, new[] { Environment.NewLine }.Concat(file1Lines));`.